# Way to deactivate/stop the scheduled batch class

Tags: chatter, schedulebatch

I have a scheduled batch class to send the chatter notification based on some criteria, now i dont want to send the notification, is there any way to deactivate/stop the scheduled class??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Setup, search for "Scheduled Jobs", find your scheduled class in the list and delete the scheduled job for your class.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Setup>Monitor>Jobs>Scheduled Jobs, and find the schedule job that you want to abort.

---

You can also stop jobs from running through the Dev Console. Open Developer Console & launch 'Open Execute Anonymous Window' & paste the below code:

```
List<CronTrigger> abort_job = [SELECT Id FROM CronTrigger WHERE NextFireTime != null limit 1];

for (CronTrigger t : abort_job) { //for each record
    System.abortJob(t.Id); //abort the job
}
```

If you know the Id of your job then you can specify the it in your where clause.